# Does the word "food' have a plural form?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I searched the net and I've found out that the word "food" doesn't have a plural form, much like furniture. So now I'm really confused. I read a lot and I've noticed that "foods" is still being used, and I still hear some native speakers of English say "foods". In addition to that, we can actually see it in food brands like "Kraft Foods" and "Best Foods". I would really appreciate it if someone can clear this for me.

It's actually a post of mine on Facebook and I'm not really sure if it's correct. It goes something like this: "Can you make processed foods healthier? The answer is you can't. There is no substitute for real and natural foods." When I said processed foods, I was pertaining to a group of processed food, not just one or generic, so is it correct?

Comment: Yes  *foods* is a proper word  just like *monies* is. Sometimes it's surprising what words are used as count nouns. Did your Internet search include a dictionary such as [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/food), which lists *food* as a count noun and gives more than one example of *foods*?

Comment: @adobo No, they are not both correct. One is correct for one thing and wrong for the other thing, while with the other the contrary relationship applies. You cannot use *food* where *foods* is required, nor vice versa. These are different things completely.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that, but thanks for the tip. There are a lot of things in the internet and it's really confusing sometimes.

Comment: @tchrist Alright, it's actually a post of mine on facebook and I'm not really sure if it's correct. It goes something like this: "Can you make processed foods healthier? The answer is you can't. There is no substitute for real and natural foods." I'll check the Oxford website for those rules.

Comment: In that example, *processed foods* sounds to me like a reference to (the group of unnamed) specific instances, whereas *processed food* refers to something more generic.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, when I said processed foods, I was pertaining to a group of processed food, not just one or generic, so is it correct?

Comment: In that case, the first instance of *foods* sounds fine. You might want to [edit] your question to incorporate the comments so that your question can stand on its own. Comments are subject to deletion at a whim, whereas questions and answers (the posts) are treated with more respect.